# loosely coupled and tightly coupled?

Tags: networking

Can someone explain the difference between the terms "loosely coupled" and "tightly coupled" with respect to networking ?

Comment: The difference is how much Superglue you want to use in your switch ports. Loosely-coupled environments needs a lot more of it.

Comment: Seriously - can you provide a little bit of context for your question? Off the top of my head, I can't really think of anything in networking that uses these terms. Application architecture, sure - interactions between systems can be sync, async, replicated, etc. Networking, not so much, at least above the physical and media-access layers.

Comment: I smell homework.

Comment: My suspicion as well - that's why I'm asking for context.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very relative term, but the basics behind this principle can be read here:

http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/loose-coupling

Comment: +1 Lacking a context for the question, this is about as good as it gets.